# Python pylab plot legend scientivic writing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, decimal, legend

I need to modify my legend. `noise_mu` has values like 1.6e-29 and I want it being plotted exactly this scientific way. Unfortunately my legend always prints them in form of 0.000000000000000000000016 . How can I change that ?!

```
pl.figure('Connectivity', figsize=(16, 9), dpi=80, facecolor="grey", frameon="True")
    pl.ion()
    pl.plot(freqs, con, label="$\mu_N: %.30f$"%noise_mu, linewidth=1.5)
    pl.ylim(0, 1.05)
    pl.xlim(freq1_start-30,freq1_end+30)
    pl.xlabel("Frequency [Hz]", color="black", fontsize=22)
    pl.ylabel("Connectivity Value [ ]", color="black", fontsize=22)
    pl.grid(all)
    xticks = np.arange(freq1_start-30,freq1_end+30,5) # change the ticks accordingly to your ROI
    pl.xticks(xticks)
    yticks = np.arange(0,1.05,0.1)
    pl.yticks(yticks)
    leg = pl.legend(prop={'size':16}, shadow=True, fancybox=True)
    for legobj in leg.legendHandles:
        legobj.set_linewidth(2.5)
    pl.show()
```

Comment: If you don't want it, why do you print it explicitly with 30 digits after the decimal point? "`%.30f`"

Comment: It was just a way to show me some numbers and due this way the mistake became clear to me. 
I will make it really clear for you now:
I want to print the 30 digit number scientifically. No need to worry why I did something in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot it without specifying formatting

```
pl.plot(freqs, con, label="$\mu_N: %g$"%noise_mu, linewidth=1.5)
```

note the `%g` instead of `%.30f`

Reference : https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html

Comment: Unfortunatly the numbers a round up to 5 decimal digits now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Sorry to bother you guys.

```
pl.figure('Connectivity', figsize=(16, 9), dpi=80, facecolor="grey", frameon="True")
pl.ion()
pl.plot(freqs, con, label="$\mu_N: %s$"%noise_mu, linewidth=1.5)
pl.ylim(0, 1.05)
pl.xlim(freq1_start-30,freq1_end+30)
pl.xlabel("Frequency [Hz]", color="black", fontsize=22)
pl.ylabel("Connectivity Value [ ]", color="black", fontsize=22)
pl.grid(all)
xticks = np.arange(freq1_start-30,freq1_end+30,5) # change the ticks accordingly to your ROI
pl.xticks(xticks)
yticks = np.arange(0,1.05,0.1)
pl.yticks(yticks)
leg = pl.legend(prop={'size':16}, shadow=True, fancybox=True)
for legobj in leg.legendHandles:
    legobj.set_linewidth(2.5)
pl.show()
```

The line has to look like this:

```
label="$\mu_N: %s$"%noise_mu
```

The `%s` is for a scientific writing.

Comment: No, %s is for string conversion, it calls `str` on your object. `%g` or `%e` is what you are looking for (check the link I posted on my answer)